# Handling multiple clients with UDP

Tags: java, udp

Imagine a UDP server:

```
while (true) {
    try {
        socket.receive(packet);
        // handle packet (potentially CPU-intensive)
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

What troubles me is that I only have 1 thread to handle all packets from all clients. I assume my server can't start multiple threads to receive packets on the same socket? While of course I could handle the packets in separate threads, I still only have 1 thread to receive datapackets, and no matter how little time it takes to forward a packet to another thread, it's still a window where the server won't hear incoming packets.

So my question is: Do packets send to the server get lost if the server isn't currently blocked in `server.receive()`, or do they get queued for the next time the method is called? If they get lost, how can I handle multiple client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do packets send to the server get lost if the server isn't currently blocked in server.receive()

No.

> or do they get queued for the next time the method is called?

They are queued in the socket receive buffer, if there is room, otherwise they are lost.

> how can I handle multiple client[s]?

Either process each packet fast enough so that the socket receive buffer never overflows, or start a new thread to handle each datagram.